# Disable VoiceOver in a WebView

Tags: cocoa, webview, accessibility, voiceover

We have an app running in a WebView with its own homespun accessibility. Switching it to use VoiceOver natively is not an option for several reasons. When VoiceOver is on, it conflicts with our accessibility, often saying two things at once.

Is there an API for turning VoiceOver on and off, or to turn off speech while focus is in our WebView?

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine there would be a way of disabling somebody's explicitly activated accessibility options; it would be bad practise to say the least!

Howabout some non-visible instructions, that are only picked up VoiceOver, asking the user to disable VoiceOver themselves when using your app?

Comment: if someone's going to mark down an answer, I'd hope they at least have the common courtesy to give some reasoning as to why.